# Javascript make arraypairs to key index list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing

[image]

I have array pair list which look like this:

```
0: [0, "535222325"]
1: [1, "346362534"]
2: [0, "534534646"]
3: [1, "745354367"]
    ^ <--- Index for array where to append value
```

How can I convert this by first value which is index key to lists look like below

```
0: ["535222325","534534646"]
1: ["346362534","745354367"]
^ <--- Unique index found from array above
```

Or how to append into key when value with matching index is found in for loop

Example of my script:

```
for(var u = 0; u < Object.keys(freshData).length; u++) {
    tag[u].Index <-- This I want to use as a key, whenever new unique match appears
    tag[u].Value <-- This I want to add in to array of that key
}
```

Sorry for extremely bad explanation. Target is just to make lists by unique keys, which are found in for loop.

Comment: Your example script assigns to `Index` and  `Value` properties, but your desired output only consists of arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reduce` to the rescue:

```js
const data = [
  [0, "535222325"],
  [1, "346362534"],
  [0, "534534646"],
  [1, "745354367"]
]

const groupKVPairs = (pairs, container = {}) => pairs.reduce(
  (acc, [key, value]) => {
    const group = acc[key]
    if (group !== undefined) group.push(value)
    else acc[key] = [value]
    return acc
  },
  container
)

console.log(groupKVPairs(data, []))
// output -> [["535222325", "534534646"], ["346362534", "745354367"]]

console.log(groupKVPairs(data, {}))
// output -> { "0": ["535222325", "534534646"], "1": ["346362534", "745354367"]}

console.log(groupKVPairs(data))
// output -> { "0": ["535222325", "534534646"], "1": ["346362534", "745354367"]}
```

Comment: Thanks! This made my day, and also I understood it finally!

Comment: @sukkis did you want an array of arrays, or an object of arrays? If you want an object, I'll update my answer. Personally, I'd prefer to return an array of arrays in this situation.

Comment: I also edited this answer to turn this into a reusable function called `groupPairs`. Just call it any time with an array of pairs to get the desired result.

Comment: As an aside: I'm not a big fan of JavaScript's implementation of `Array.prototype.concat`, since it concats if passed an array but appends if passed anything else. i.e. `[].concat(['a']) //-> ['a'] (concats)` but also `[].concat('a') //-> ['a'] (appends)`. I use `concat`, but it's important to understand these different behaviors you should expect, depending whether you call it with an array or with something else.

Comment: I made one last edit. Now you can decide whether you want the results to be packaged in an object or an array. If you want an array, either call the function with an array as the second argument or simply leave off the second argument. If you want an object, pass in an object as the second argument. With that, I think it's probably pretty reusable and configurable for various scenarios.

Comment: ok, I made a couple more edits. I renamed the function to groupKVPairs and use an object as the default container type (since that seems more flexible). I also improved the efficiency of the function - I believe it's about as efficient as it can be, now (without incorporating a `for` loop rather than relying on `reduce`, at least). Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.reduce function to produce desired object like below..

```js
var ar = [
  [0, "535222325"],
  [1, "346362534"],
  [0, "534534646"],
  [1, "745354367"]
]
var res = ar.reduce((mem, [first, last]) => ({ ...mem,
  [first]: [...mem[first] || [], last]
}), {});
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`:

```js
var arr = [
  [0, "535222325"],
  [1, "346362534"],
  [0, "534534646"],
  [1, "745354367"]
];

var obj = arr.reduce((r, [key, val]) => (r[key] = (r[key]||[]).concat([val])) && r, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I guess this is most efficent way to solve my problem, thanks for great answer.

Comment: @sukkis Actually, a solution relying on `concat` (or the ES6 spread operator) will be less efficient than one relying on `push` since `concat` and the spread operator create a new array rather than mutating the existing one. Furthermore, if you ever want to use this function on an array of pairs where the value part of a pair can be an array, `concat` may give you unexpected results, since it will flatten the value arrays.